# What are some syntax options for wildcard matching? (+ extensions)

Tags: syntax

By "wildcard matching" I mean the following:

- `*` matches zero or more of any characters. E.g. `B*` matches any string starting with `B`, including just `B`.
- `?` matches any one character. E.g. `???` matches any string that is exactly three characters long.
- `[abc]` matches any of the enclosed characters (with a few exceptions noted below). E.g. `[HCB]at` matches `Hat`, `Cat`, or `Bat`.
- `[x-y]` matches any character in the specified range. E.g. `[0-9]` matches any digit.
- `[^...]` negates the character class. E.g. `[^0-9]` matches any non-digit character.

The above is the syntax commonly used in tools like `glob` (which also usually have a few path-specific features not mentioned above). SQL also supports similar, but using `%` instead of `*`, and `_` instead of `?`.

I don't care about path-specific variants or extensions such as path separators, `**`, or ignored leading `.`, this is focused on string matching specifically.

Some variants I found already:

- [At least one database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/structured-query-language/like-operator-microsoft-access-sql) supports `#` as a synonym for `[0-9]`.
- Bash supports an [extended version of globbing](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing), using syntax like `?(...)` (one or zero of the enclosed patterns), `*(...)` (zero or more of the enclosed patterns), etc. (Bash also supports more complex extensions such as alternation, which is closer to regex and hence a little beyond the scope of this question.)
- Many glob and SQL implementations support `[!...]` for negation of a character class instead of/in addition to `[^...]`.

So, my question is, are there any other syntax options for this? And are there any other extensions I'm not aware of here? I'm not looking for something as complex as a regex here (e.g. alternation, backtracking or similar is too much).

Comment: Is this about paths or strings? For paths, ** would also be common. I'd also rephrase it to uncommon ways, because, to me, your list looks already like obscure examples. "Glob" should also be clarified.

Comment: You say "alternation ... is too much",  but refer to the "extended glob syntax" found in bash, which implements a form of alternation. A simpler form based on list expansion is also common, e.g. [.editorconfig files](https://editorconfig.org/) allow `{foo,bar}` and `{1..9}`. I don't think there's a clear line between "extended glob-like matching" and "simple regex-like matching".

Comment: @feldentm updated to clarify.

Comment: @IMSoP you are right that there's no clear line, e.g. the extended glob I linked earlier has alternation, whereas some regex-style patterns (e.g. in Lua) don't have any alternation.  Maybe I should edit to allow any extensions to wildcard matching.